# Firebase infinite scroll startAt +1

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I got a list of posts in firebase:

```
idcreatedfromfirebase1
idcreatedfromfirebase2
idcreatedfromfirebase3
idcreatedfromfirebase4
idcreatedfromfirebase5
```

I´m using infinite scroll with:

```
// get first item from firebase  
var firstItem = "";

firebase.database().ref("posts").orderByPriority().startAt().limitToFirst(5).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
      $scope.lastValue = snapshot.val();  
});
```

Now the last ID of the retrieved post is in `$scope.lastValue`.
If I call my infinite scroll function again with the lastValue in `startAt()` again, the last post from the previous call is the same then the first post from the actual call.

How to get the lastValue+1 post from firebase?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to offset that last/first item (often referred to as the anchor item).

You'll have to skip it in your code, for example by checking if you already have a UI element for `snapshot.key`.